# Is there a way to add a Docker Webhook programmatically?

Tags: docker

say I set up OAuth.. I can use that access with the Registry API to do registry stuff.. what I want is for people to be able to set up automated builds and then when that is done a webhook automatically sets off a deployment on my server.

I would like to automatically create this Webhook. Is there an API to do that? Thanks.

See https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/#webhooks

Comment: I added a link explaining Webhooks at the end.